# Merge Insta360 INSV files into 360 video with ffmpeg 360vr filter

Tags: ffmpeg, 360video

Insta produces 2 video files, from back and front camera. They have .INSV extenstion, but they are acutally mp4 video files. That's how they look:

[image]

[image]

And expected result is 360 panorama video:
[image]

Can I use ffmpeg with 360 filter to get result as above? I mean that filter: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#v360

I can use Insta360 studio, but as I'm on Linux, I'm getting some troubles to use it (my video card driver opengl version is too old to run it on Wine). Also, I preffer command line interface for batch convert files.

So, can I use ffmpeg to do that (or any other Linux tool)?